# postgres cumsum multiplication and update price

Tags: postgresql

1. With the Postgres 13 SQL statement in the link and in the following the field `incorrectly_calc_value_b` is not calculated correctly.

   ```
       select date_actual,transaction_date, new_price_date,item_name, quantity, 
                             SUM((SELECT quantity as B_alloc
                              WHERE item_name='B')) OVER (
                                 ORDER by date.date_actual 
                                 RANGE BETWEEN unbounded PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                             ) as CUM_inv_B,
                             price_B, right_cum_value_B,
                             SUM((SELECT (quantity*price_date.price_B) as B_value
                              WHERE item_name='B')) OVER (
                                 ORDER by date.date_actual 
                                 RANGE BETWEEN unbounded PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                             ) as incorrectly_calc_value_B
                FROM date 
                LEFT JOIN item_ ON item_.transaction_date=date.date_actual
                FULL JOIN price_date ON price_date.new_price_date=date.date_actual
                ORDER BY date.date_actual DESC
   ```

The data in all fields are correct except the incorrectly_calc_value_B.

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=24b61887528470a2b3b8e50d490b373e)

I tried `SUM(cum_inv_B*price_B)` for the calculation but that did not work.

```
ERROR:  column "cum_inv_b" does not exist
LINE 8:    SUM((SELECT (CUM_inv_B*pric...
```

The `right_cumlative_value_B` is manually entered and would like to know how to correct my statement below.

To get the incorrect values I have currently :

```
SUM((SELECT (quantity*price_date.price_B) as B_value
                              WHERE item_name='B')) OVER (
                                 ORDER by date.date_actual 
                                 RANGE BETWEEN unbounded PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                             ) as incorrectly_calc_value_B
```

2. My 2nd question , since the price_B is null (which is correct) on some dates, how do I correct the carryover everyday until price B changes ? For example, on 2021-04-05 the price changed to 79. Instead of null, on 04-06 and 04-07 the price needs to be both 79. The price_B is correct on 04-08 with 80 because it changed from 79 to 80.

Comment: Please post expected output..

Comment: I cannot address your main issue. Need test data and expected results for that. But as for null values 2 choices come to mind: add a where condition  "and price_date.price_B is not null" or instead select "[coalesce](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-coalesce/)(price_date.price_B,0).  Same could apply to *quantity* whoever it comes from.  And who knows solving that may just resolve the other as wall.

Comment: The expected result is not clear in my explanation. It was in the DB fiddle as the column "right_cum_value_b" for question 1. I will try the coalesce.